# Black screen occurs while taking screenshot in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using a native surface view in a flutter When I take a screenshot using a repaint boundary widget. black screen issue occurs.

**My code :**

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =_globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
ByteData byteData =
await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
```

Please guide me for solution